# Raytracing many objects and exporting shaded ground as a raster

Tags: r, shadow, raytracing, rgl

I have models consisting of thousands of cylinders which are stored in a data frame with start-coordinates, end-coordinates, lengths and radii. I want to simulate the shading they would create in the real world, given a certain position of a light source. As a result, I would like to have a raster which contains the information whether the ground is shaded or not (on the xy-plane). Is there a way to do this in R? Even when handling several thousand cylinder objects at the same time?

Here a mockup for a single cylinder:

[image]

I usually draw my cylinders with the `rgl` package, but it would be also okay if I have to use another package. I figured I might be able to use the packages `rayrender` or `raytracing`, but I don't know to export the shaded ground from the view to an array or raster.

**Edit**: Code for creating & plotting some cylinders:

```
library(rgl)

# some cylinders
cylinder <- structure(list(radius = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01), length = c(0.07, 0.13, 0.08, 0.08, 0.1, 0.08, 0.09, 
0.08, 0.07, 0.15, 0.02, 0.09, 0.12, 0.12, 0.08, 0.26, 0.1, 0.09, 
0.08, 0.02, 0.12, 0.11, 0.08, 0.06, 0.06, 0.19, 0.05, 0.1, 0.09, 
0.09), start_X = c(0.62, 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65, 0.65, 
0.63, 0.63, 0.63, 0.63, 0.64, 0.63, 0.69, 0.79, 0.81, 0.92, 0.97, 
1.03, 1.07, 1.08, 1.15, 1.24, 1.3, 1.34, 0.61, 0.5, 0.47, 0.4, 
0.37), start_Y = c(0.13, 0.11, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.08, 0.09, 
0.08, 0.07, 0.08, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, 0.05, 0.02, 0.04, 0.02, 0.01, 
0.04, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.19, 0.22, 0.07, 0.13, 0.16, 0.17, 
0.26), start_Z = c(361, 361.07, 361.2, 361.29, 361.36, 361.46, 
361.54, 361.62, 361.7, 361.77, 361.9, 361.92, 361.78, 361.88, 
361.98, 362.04, 362.26, 362.35, 362.39, 362.46, 362.48, 362.56, 
362.62, 362.65, 362.66, 361.76, 361.91, 361.95, 362.01, 362.07
), axis_X = c(-0.09, 0.05, 0.12, 0.14, 0.1, -0.03, -0.15, -0.07, 
-0.07, -0.2, 0.52, -0.62, 0.43, 0.54, 0.16, 0.35, 0.53, 0.43, 
0.76, 0.58, 0.63, 0.74, 0.66, 0.56, 0.79, -0.61, -0.65, -0.64, 
-0.33, -0.7), axis_Y = c(-0.12, -0.09, -0.01, -0.08, -0.08, 0.01, 
-0.11, -0.14, -0.04, -0.06, 0.06, 0.59, -0.14, -0.14, 0.38, -0.22, 
0.1, 0, 0.14, 0.15, 0.47, 0.45, 0.46, 0.67, 0.48, 0.28, 0.2, 
0, 0.55, 0.16), axis_Z = c(0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1, 0.98, 
0.99, 1, 0.98, 0.85, 0.53, 0.89, 0.83, 0.91, 0.91, 0.84, 0.9, 
0.64, 0.8, 0.61, 0.5, 0.59, 0.48, -0.39, 0.74, 0.74, 0.77, 0.77, 
0.69)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

# calculate end points of cylinders
# (cylinders have starting coordinates, a length and a direction as unit vector)
cylinder$end_X = cylinder$start_X + cylinder$axis_X * cylinder$length
cylinder$end_Y = cylinder$start_Y + cylinder$axis_Y * cylinder$length
cylinder$end_Z = cylinder$start_Z + cylinder$axis_Z * cylinder$length
  
# prepare cylinders
cylinder_list <- lapply(1:nrow(cylinder), function(i) {
  cyl <- cylinder3d(
    center = cbind(
      c(cylinder$start_X[i], cylinder$end_X[i]),
      c(cylinder$start_Y[i], cylinder$end_Y[i]),
      c(cylinder$start_Z[i], cylinder$end_Z[i])),
    radius = cylinder$radius[i],
    closed = -2)
  cyl
})

# plot cylinders
open3d()
par3d(windowRect = c(50,50,650, 650))
shade3d(shapelist3d(cylinder_list, plot = FALSE), color = "blue")
```

I would like the light source to be a point source from infinite distance, as I would like to simulate sunlight. As the sun is so far away, I would just assume the light beams to be parallel to each other.

Comment: I'd guess you can do this with the `rgl::shadow3d()` function:  create each cylinder as a mesh, project it onto a plane, and display the plane.

Comment: Another way to do this is to set up a projection matrix that projects all the cylinders into a plane.  I'd be happy to expand on the comment, if you add some code to your question to create some cylinders, and give more description about what sort of projection you want (i.e. shadows from a point source at finite distance, or infinite distance?).

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I added some example cylinder data and how I usually plot them!

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  I was travelling today, but I hope by tomorrow I'll have something to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```r
library(rgl)

# some cylinders
# ... deleted ...

# cylinder$start_Z <- cylinder$start_Z -  361.5

# calculate end points of cylinders
# (cylinders have starting coordinates, a length and a direction as unit vector)
cylinder$end_X = cylinder$start_X + cylinder$axis_X * cylinder$length
cylinder$end_Y = cylinder$start_Y + cylinder$axis_Y * cylinder$length
cylinder$end_Z = cylinder$start_Z + cylinder$axis_Z * cylinder$length

# prepare cylinders
cylinder_list <- lapply(1:nrow(cylinder), function(i) {
  cyl <- cylinder3d(
    center = cbind(
      c(cylinder$start_X[i], cylinder$end_X[i]),
      c(cylinder$start_Y[i], cylinder$end_Y[i]),
      c(cylinder$start_Z[i], cylinder$end_Z[i])),
    radius = cylinder$radius[i],
    closed = -2)
  cyl
})

cylinder_list <- shapelist3d(cylinder_list, plot = FALSE)

# plot cylinders
open3d()
#> glX 
#>   1
par3d(windowRect = c(50,50,650, 650))
# shade3d(cylinder_list, color = "blue")

# Suppose Sun is in direction xyz

sun <- c(0,0,1) #  straight up

# Get a matrix that projects sun to c(0,0,0),
# and leaves anything with z = 0 alone

M <- rbind( cbind( diag(2), c(-sun[1]/sun[3], -sun[2]/sun[3])), 0)

# Replot the shadows of the cylinders

shadows <- transform3d(cylinder_list, t(M))
shade3d(shadows, col = "gray", lit = FALSE)

# decorate3d()   # Add axes

par3d(userMatrix = diag(4)) # Display flat.

lowlevel() # And show it in reprex
```

[image]

```r
# Use snapshot3d() to get PNG file containing the final image
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

It should include your definition of the `cylinders` dataframe, but I left that out to make it easier to read.

If you want to show the cylinders as well as the shadows, uncomment the `shade3d()` call on `cylinder_list`.  You'll probably also want to make the `Z` values smaller; I subtracted 361.5 to put them near zero.  If you don't do this, the graph will be extremely long and thin, and you won't be able to see anything.

The idea of the code is to project the `sun` vector to `c(0,0,0)`, while leaving anything with `Z==0` alone.  This flattens the cylinders into objects that fit in the `Z == 0` plane.  Setting the `userMatrix` to the identity matrix then displays the shadow.  Use the `snapshot3d()` function to make this into a raster image (in a PNG file).

Comment: Forgot to mention:  you'll probably need to install `rgl` from Github; this code turned up a couple of bugs, which have been fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, this is great! I really appreciate the effort. Do you know, by any chance, if there is a way to export `rgl` 3D plots in a way that I know the scale of the image? E.g. knowing what the size of one pixel is in real life? Or is this not possible?

Comment: That's probably possible, but it would be a relatively messy calculation, because `rgl` adapts the scale to the data. What I'd do is plot some reference points outside the range of your data:  they'll determine the scale.  Then just measure where they end up in the final plot.  That will stay consistent as long as they determine the scale.

Comment: Hey, I wanted to give a small update: I can extract the cylinder vertices from the `shadows` object, create convex hulls around them, and then rasterize convex hull polygons. I don't need to actually plot the shadows and try to convert it into a raster on my desired scale. Unfortunately, this procedure is too slow for my application.